# Как добавить счётчик от 10 попыток ввода пароля в поле?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
static int counter = 0; //статическое поле формы
```

В обработчик кнопки Button

```
counter++;
if (textBox1.Text == "пароль") // проверяем пароль так или другими способами
{
    //что-то делаем
}
else if (counter >= 5) // лимит превышен
{
    textBox1.Enabled = false; //блокируем текстбокс
}
```

А как сделать такое:

На форме есть `label` ставлю ему счётчик 5 - 10 попыток

После не правильного ввода, этот счётчик должен отнимается, и когда достигает нуля то выполняется `textBox1.Enabled = false; //блокируем текстбокс`

Comment: `static int counter = 5; //статическое поле формы` .... `counter--;` ..... `else if (counter <= 0) {....}`

Comment: @tym32167, а чтобы в label отображалось действия уменьшения?

Comment: `counter--; .... myLabel.Text = counter.ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int counter = 5; //статическое поле формы
```

В обработчик кнопки Button

```
counter--;
myLabel.Text = counter.ToString();

if (textBox1.Text == "пароль") // проверяем пароль так или другими способами
{
    //что-то делаем
}
else if (counter <= 0) // лимит превышен
{
    textBox1.Enabled = false; //блокируем текстбокс
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)